# non liner animation strips have rotate problem

Tags: nla-editor

[image]

trying to make loop animation by mixing .mdd  animation by NLA window.

as base model has no transform(position at 0, rotateion is 0)
first import animation by mdd, and duplicated strip,
then the object rotate 90 degrees when the second strip starts. is there any possibily solutions??

I could not upload blend file somehow, but the picture.first strip and second strip has different rotate.
[image]

(this picture below is about the added file, this object is the one i want to export and make loop animation)
[image]

Comment: Can you add a sample blend file to your question that shows the problem? ([How to add a blend file](https://blend-exchange.com/help))

Comment: thank you for the reply, I added file and this link is the tutorial i followed > https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=U7oistIgo1U

Comment: I found one solution. its not straight forward though,  I deleted first frame and last frame after importing mdd file. then It got no rotation problem.